# Javascript global variable and namespace

Tags: javascript, namespaces, global

I'm trying to understand why a tab isn't updated with values entered through a form.

The program is made up of three parts:

1. tasks10.html with the form and tasks10.js call
2. utilities10.js grouping the  functions into an object U = {...} to create a namespace. The function used to populate the tab is named plusTask.
3. tasks10.js   an immediately invoked function which purpose is to assign 'onsubmit' event the function U.plusTask

I put the declaration var tasks = []; in tasks10.js => failed; in plusTask => failed. In both cases the tab isn't populated and the index still remain 0.

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title>List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/form.css">
</head>
<body>      
    <form action="#" method="post" id="theForm">
        <fieldset><legend>Enter an Item To Be Done</legend>
            <div><label for="task">Task</label><input type="text" name="task" id="task" required></div>
            <input type="submit" value="Add It!" id="submit">
            <div id="output"></div>
            <p id='test'> -- </p>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <script src="js/utilities10.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tasks10.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

tasks10.js

```
(function() {   // immediately invoked function
    'use strict';
    //window.addEventListener('onsubmit',U.plusTask,false);
    U.$('theForm').onsubmit = U.plusTask;
})(); // End of anonymous function.
```

utilities10.js

```
var U = {
    // For getting the document element by ID:
    $: function(id) {
        'use strict';
        if (typeof id == 'string') {
            //alert("cxcwcw  $"+ id);
            return document.getElementById(id); 
        }
    }, // End of $() function.

    plusTask : function() {
        var tasks = [];

        // Function called when the form is submitted.
        // Function adds a task to the global array.

        function innerCalculate(){
            alert(tasks.length);
            'use strict';

            // Get the task:
            //var task =this.$('task');
             var task =U.$('task'); alert("task : " + task);
            //var task =document.getElementById('task'); 

            // Reference to where the output goes:
            //var output = this.$('output');
            var output = U.$('output');
            //var output = document.getElementById('output');
            alert("in");

            // For the output:
            var message = '';

            if (task.value) {
            U.$('test').innerHTML = tasks.length;
            //document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = tasks.length;
                // Add the item to the array:
                tasks.push(task.value);

                // Update the page:
                message = '<h2>To-Do</h2><ol>';
                for (var i = 0, count = tasks.length; i < count; i++) {
                    message += '<li>' + this.tasks[i] + ' - ' + count + '</li>';
                }
                message += '</ol>';
                output.innerHTML = message;

            } // End of task.value IF.

            // Return false to prevent subssmission:
            return false;

        } // End of innerCalculate
        innerCalculate();

    } // End of plusTask function
} // End of U
```

Answer (score 0):

The `plusTask` function resets all of its local variables every time it's called.

I think you meant to use an IIFE to create a closure. Also, `this.tasks[i]` should be `tasks[i]`.

```
plusTask : (function() { // IIFE
    var tasks = [];
    function innerCalculate() {
        alert(tasks.length);
        'use strict';
        var task = U.$('task');
        alert("task : " + task);
        var output = U.$('output');
        alert("in");
        var message = '';
        if (task.value) {
            U.$('test').innerHTML = tasks.length;
            tasks.push(task.value);
            message = '<h2>To-Do</h2><ol>';
            for (var i = 0, count = tasks.length; i < count; i++) {
                message += '<li>' + tasks[i] + ' - ' + count + '</li>';
            }
            message += '</ol>';
            output.innerHTML = message;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return innerCalculate; // return closure
})() // invoke plusTask IIFE
```

Answer (score 0):

On line 44 you had:

```
message += '<li>' + this.tasks[i] + ' - ' + count + '</li>';
```

But the tasks you wanted are the one from the closure, while "this" is Window. So instead you want:

```
message += '<li>' + tasks[i] + ' - ' + count + '</li>';
```

Additionally, if you pressed submit here it would reload the page. So plusTask should start something like this:

```
plusTask : function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
```

Comment: Actually, in this case `this` would be `U` since it's inside an object. Good catch

Comment: Hmm, maybe I made a mistake, but I was looking at "this" inside of the debugger at that line and strongly recall it saying it was "Window".

Comment: You're right, I was thinking of what the value would be once it was used as a closure.

Answer (score 0):

Bemmu, Castle, good job! I should have thought about closure and missed using this. Final js code is doing the job. Thank you both.  :

```
<pre>
plusTask : (function(e) { // IIFE           
   var tasks = [];

   function innerCalculate(e) {
       if(typeof e == 'undefined') e = window.event;            
          alert(tasks.length);
          'use strict';
          var task = U.$('task');
          alert("task : " + task);
          var output = U.$('output');
          alert("in");
          var message = '';
        if (task.value) {
              U.$('test').innerHTML = tasks.length;
              tasks.push(task.value);
             message = '<h2>To-Do</h2><ol>';
                for (var i = 0, count = tasks.length; i < count; i++) {
                    message += '<li>' + tasks[i] + ' - ' + count + '</li>';
                }
                message += '</ol>';
                output.innerHTML = message;
            }
            // Return false to prevent submission:
            if (e.preventDefault) {
                e.preventDefault();
                } else {
                e.returnValue = false;
                    }

     return false;
      }
    return innerCalculate; // return closure
  })() // invoke plusTask IIFE
 </pre>
```

Comment: If you want to give thanks, upvoting and accepting answers would be the way to go.

Comment: I'm reading the doc for new users in Stakoverflow. Don't know yet how to upvote and accept answers. ?